# how to format a time like 10:30 Am

Tags: c#

here is code .......

```
        SqlConnection con9 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conec"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd9;
        string sql9 = " SELECT  DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00', Total_time)), '00:00') as times FROM Todaywork Where Date='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy") + "'";
        try
        {
            con9.Open();
            cmd9 = new SqlCommand(sql9, con9);
            string value = cmd9.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            cmd9.Dispose();
            con9.Close();
            lbltimeworktoday.Text =value.ToString();
```

i want that  lbltimeworktoday.text = something like 10:30 AM format how can i do it?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters instead.

Comment: Don't convert your DateTime value to string - pass it as a typed parameter.

Comment: [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: If you want to do it purely on the SQL size, use SQL's CONVERT function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles).  But, you are **_Much_** better off using a DateTime on the C# side of the query and formatting it using C#'s rich and consistent formatting

Answer (score 2):

```
string formattedTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"h:mm tt")
```

Comment: it gives me current date and time ...but i want that database column of time is been format ..

Comment: @FazalAbbas: Select the value from the database (which I'm assuming is a Date or a DateTime (or one of the date/time types) into a C# DateTime variable.  Then format it as is shown above